# Writing a dictionary to file with biopython

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm new using biopython... I'm trying to write a dictionary to a file, using biopython. Here is my code:

```
with open("file_in.fasta") as original, open("file_out.fasta", "w") as corrected:
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(original,'fasta'):
        desc=seq_record.description
        seq_dict={seq_record.id + '_1':seq_record.seq}
        SeqIO.write(seq_dict.values(),corrected,'fasta')
```

But I get this error: AttributeError: 'Seq' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: what are you trying to do? add `_1` to the end of each `>` line? Using a dictionary is not needed for this

Comment: yes and then write it to a new fasta file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your aim of wanting to add `_1` to the end of each `>` line, you don't need a dictionary, you can just modify the sequence record directly:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("file_in.fasta") as original, open("file_out.fasta", "w") as corrected:
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(original,'fasta'):
        seq_record.description += '_1'
        seq_record.id = seq_record.description.split()[0]
        SeqIO.write(seq_record, corrected, 'fasta')
```

Modifying both the `.description` and `.id` like this is important

Note this would also be a simple task with unix tools like `sed`, you don't really need Biopython unless you're doing something else too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did this same script but adding _2 into another file. But now I want to concatenate two files and I'm using copy file1.fasta+file2.fasta > both.fastam however I only get one file in the final file.

Comment: @Sofia you should probably ask a separate question, then.